# Invoking a modal dialog to collect some information in JQuery ajax beforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and JQuery. I want to know if its possible to invoke a bootstrap modal dialog before making an ajax call in **'$.ajax beforeSend'**? I want to collect user comments before submitting the form. I have several buttons on my page that require this behavior. So, I want to make it more generic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the use of jQuery's `Deferred` object (see http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).
The following is pseudo code for your buttons' event handler:

```
$('#theButton').on('click', function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    // Code to show modal dialog here.
    // Pass dfd to the dialog, and have it call dfd.resolve() 
    // when the user has finished, or dfd.reject() in case the
    // user does not complete the form.

    dfd.done(function() {
        // Ajax call here
    });
});
```

The function that gets passed to `dfd.done()` as an argument gets only called if and when somebody calls the `resolve()` method on the Deferred object.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the asynchronous event model in javascript, you cannot *postpone* the ajax request from being sent off from within `beforeSend`. Once `beforeSend` is executed, the only chance you have to "delay" the ajax request is to outright cancel it entirely by returning false from the callback.

So while you could keep track of a status variable that knows whether the form is ready to submit (return false from `beforeSend` whenever the form is not ready), you're much better off doing these validation checks before ever creating the ajax request to begin with.

```
// why do this
$.ajax('/path', {
    beforeSend: function () {
        if (formIsNotReady()) {
            showModal();
            return false;
        }
    }
});

// when you can do this
if (formIsNotReady()) {
    showModal();
} else {
    $.ajax('/path');
}
```